# Is it possible to find ContentDocument and attach that file to a FeedItem through a flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, chatter, contentdocument, feeditem, chatter-feed

I am trying to create a feeditem and trying to find a documentcontent file and attaching it to this feeditem through a flow.

I think I can find the version of the contentdocument by looking at the contentdocumentlink and using the linkedentityid to relate it back to the feeditem.

I need to somehow attach this file to the feeditem like what was done below.

Is it possible? As you can see it has been done on our org but Im not sure how it was done previously.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference you want to use is the schema for [Chatter Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_chatter.htm)

- Once the FeedItem has been created and you've located the `ContentDocument` (which points at the latest `ContentVersion`) ..

  - Create a [FeedAttachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feedattachment.htm?q=feedattachment) as a child to FeedItem

    - `FeedEntityId` is the lookup to the FeedItem
    - `RecordId` is either a `ContentDocumentID` (inline images) or `ContentVersionId` (attachment)
    - `Title` is some name
    - `Type` is as per the doc

Comment: Thanks for that, this is a good solution. I used a flow got the contentversion id of my PDF. However I am getting this error. Attachment Record ID: id value of incorrect type: Also tried the contentdocument id and i got the same error. Not sure what to do so that it will accept the id i want to use???

Comment: OH nvm I think i may have worked it out. I didnt add the type

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the relationship between Content Documents, Content Versions, and Content Document Links. Basically:

- Content Document represents the file in the abstract. But “real”
  versions of this document are distinct and have different version
  numbers, so there’s also a…
- Content Version represents a specific version of the Content
  Document. A Content Document can have multiple    Content Versions
- Content Document Link is used to connect a Content    Docum ent to a
  record.

Also see information [on this page.](https://unofficialsf.com/using-files-and-attachments-in-flow/)

My guess is that you need to be manipulating the appropriate ContentVersion